# Python. How to deal with No module named 'construct' when installing pykeepass?

Tags: python, pip, construct, keepass

I am trying to install `pykeepass` library on my python environment. I have successfully installed all the other pip libraries I need to work with, but can't seem to install this one. I use python with a software I work with. The python is installed in the location of this software. Python version is 3.7.9. I navigate to the folder python is installed in and run the command: `python -m pip install pykeepass` (which was working wonderfully on my previous environment). The output I get is:

(I did clear some locations and names in this output)

```
Collecting pykeepass
Using cached pykeepass-4.0.1.tar.gz (48 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ..\python\lib\site-packages (from pykeepass) (2.8.1)
Collecting construct==2.10.54
Using cached construct-2.10.54.tar.gz (55 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "..\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-v1_9y764\construct_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
      from construct.version import version_string
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'construct'
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I did also try to install the construct, as suggested in many, many forums, but, when trying to install construct, I do end up with the same error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'construct'`

Comment: https://github.com/construct/construct/issues/924

Comment: The current latest version of `construct` is [2.10.67](https://pypi.org/project/construct/2.10.67/). Try upgrading: `pip install -U construct`

Comment: @phd I just tried upgrading, but it gave again the same error